# Is there a way to retrieve the Properties and Values used in a JMeter sampler into a JSR223 postprocessor and print them?

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, I have a JMS Subscriber sampler with some configured properties and values, such as

```
Destination: dynamicQueues/someQueue
Timeout (ms): someVariable

etc.
```

I would like to use a JSR223 Postprocessor as a child of the JMS Subscriber sampler and get those values into the postprocessor so that I can print them.

Is that possible?